# Jquery jFrame not working in IE but is in FF

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox, printing

Hey all i am trying to get this jFrame to work in IE8/9 since it has no problem working in FF.

The code to print an image is this:

```
function PrintElem(elem) 
{ 
var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());
var jFrame = $( "<iframe name='" + strFrameName + "'>" );

jFrame
    .css( "width", "1px" )
    .css( "height", "1px" )
    .css( "position", "absolute" )
    .css( "left", "-9999px" )
    .appendTo( $( "body:first" ) )
;

var objFrame = window.frames[ strFrameName ];
var objDoc = objFrame.document;
var theHTML = $(elem).html();

theHTML = theHTML.replace("display:none","display:inline"); 
objDoc.open();
objDoc.write( "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">" );
objDoc.write( "<html>" );
objDoc.write( "<body>" );
objDoc.write( "<head>" );
objDoc.write( "</head>" );
objDoc.write(theHTML);
objDoc.write( "</body>" );
objDoc.write( "</html>" );
objDoc.close();
objFrame.focus();
objFrame.print();
}
```

And i set it off doing this:

```
 <div id="printable"><IMG SRC="picturesFromServer.asp?PhotoId=310481" style="display:none;"></div>
 <IMG SRC="picturesFromServer.asp?PhotoId=310481" width="240" height="320"><br>
 </form>

 <input type="button" value="Print Division" onclick="PrintElem('#printable')" />
```

It displays the page just fine in FF and prints it but in IE it only shows the current page.

I am using the code that i found from this website for the jFrame: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm

And help would be great!

David

Comment: Take a look at http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/, it works on Firefox too.

Comment: @arunes: That doesnt seem to work half the time i test the demo site out...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jFrame.css( "opacity", "0" ).css( "height", "0px" ).appendTo($("body:first"));
```

it works for me. display:none; will not recognized by ie.